# React Native 0.57.x <Image/> large images low quality

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, components, bundler

There is really low quality when loading large bundled images, even when using `resizeMethod="resize"`. **This happens only on Android, not on any iOS simulator/device**. Have tested it on Android 8.1 emulator and LG G6 with Android 8.0. Please see the screenshots bellow.

[image]
[image]

At the left screenshot we see the exact same code running with **RN 0.56.0** and at the right screenshot we see **RN 0.57.5**. The code is just a simple image `<Image source={require('./assets/ELHall1.png')} resizeMethod="resize" />` and the image size is `2111 x 4645 pixels`. Both projects are fresh installed using `react-native init RN057ImageTest` and `react-native init --version="0.56.0" RN056ImageTest`.

**Simple App with an Image**

```
...
type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {/*<Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>{instructions}</Text>*/}
        <Image source={require('./assets/ELHall1.png')} resizeMethod="resize" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
...
```

I have created a [Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21301) to RN repo since September but noone has replied which makes me think that I am doing something wrong. Is there a new prop or an other way to make large images show normal with full quality in **RN 0.57.x**? Maybe the metr obuilder updates to **0.57.x** have changed how the bundler handles the image assets? I have used `resizeMethod` prop to `"scale"` and `"resize"` with no difference at all. I have used `PNG8`, `PNG24` and `PNG32` all same result.

**EDIT**

The [Github repo](https://github.com/clytras/RN057ImageTest) with the code and the PNG image files: https://github.com/clytras/RN057ImageTest
Please don't give any answers about JPEG images and that they do work, I [already know that](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21301#issuecomment-424284870); I want to make PNG images work like they do in RN 0.56.

**UPDATE JAN/2020**

This is an update for people landing here regarding this issue.

The [RN Issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21301) has been closed since August 10, 2019 with the statement that this is [not a React Native issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21301#issuecomment-520111321) but rather a Fresco issue.

I have created an [issue at Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/2397) on August 22, 2019 and after some conversations and talkings, the only way for now to disable image downsample, is to compile Fresco from source after removing/comment out the downsample code inside [`DecodeProducer.java`](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/v2.0.0/imagepipeline/src/main/java/com/facebook/imagepipeline/producers/DecodeProducer.java#L158-L169).

I have created a repository that has RN 0.61 and has detailed instructions on how to compile Fresco and disable image downsample. The repository can be found here: https://github.com/clytras/RN061FrescoBuild.

It turns out Fresco has a bug and does not apply Fresco configuration using `ImagePipelineConfig` and `MainPackageConfig` inside `MainApplication.java`, you can see more details about this [here](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/2397#issuecomment-576399299). RN has downsampling disabled by default! Until Fresco fixes this issue, the only way to disable image downsampling is to compile Fresco from source after removing the downsample code.

**UPDATE FEB/2020**

I have created a [react-native-community/cli](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli) template that has RN 0.61.5 project and the required modifications to build Fresco from source. This is an easy and quick way to have a new RN project crafted with custom project name and with the changes needed to compile Fresco from source. It also uses **Android NDK Revision 21** and I have tested it on macOS and Windows using yarn 1.21.

Github repository: [clytras/react-native-fresco](https://github.com/clytras/react-native-fresco)
NPM template: [@lytrax/react-native-fresco](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@lytrax/react-native-fresco)

It can be installed like this:

```
npx @react-native-community/cli@next init --template=@lytrax/react-native-fresco <ProjectName>
```

There are detailed installation instruction in the [README](https://github.com/clytras/react-native-fresco#readme). You need to clone/patch Fresco using `yarn fresco-setup` and then install Android NDK and create `android/libraries/fresco/local.properties` with Android NDK path.

Comment: What about resizeMode="contain"?also what if you add a maxWidth:"100%" property to the style?if nothing works so i believe that the issue maybe is in another place maybe some settings within device that control dpis or scale in a specific way?

Comment: @LastBreath I know about EN image scaling but I haven't tried that. I'll give it a try soon and I'll reply back here. Also, I do not care for `contain` `resizeMode`.

Comment: @LastBreath None of the `resizeMode` options sovle the quality problem. Also setting the width to 100% does nothing and the bad quality remains. That can't be possible, device settings/capabilities are not related here. Don't forget that it works perfectly at the same devices/emulators using **RN 0.56**.

Comment: did you try width or maxWidth ?

Comment: No I haven't tried maxWidth, I'll give it a shot tomorrow but I don't think it's related to the image quality issue.

Comment: @LastBreath `maxWidth` does not work either. I have uploaded a github repo. Check the question to get the link if you want.

Comment: I have same issue with remote image (jpeg and png)

Answer (score 3):

I tested [FastImage](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image) and it had a better quality

```
<FastImage source={require('./assets/ELHall1.png')} style={{height: '100%', aspectRatio: 2.5}} />
```

Comment: I am aware of FastImage; I don't use it for bundled assets, I only use it for remote images. My problem/question is, why large bundled images work fine with **RN 0.56** `<Image/>` and don't wotk with **RN 0.57.x** `<Image/>`.

Comment: Still blurry with FastImage imo

Answer (score 2):

Most of the times it is the dimensions of the Image that matter, UI designers make Designs to standard high end Mobile phones(with fixed Screen Size) and export the Images as .png to xhdpi,xxhdpi and xxxhdpi resolutions. So developers rename those Images by appending @1x, @2x & @3x to those resolutions. Example: `ELHall1@1x ,ELHall1@2x, ELHall1@3x`.

When Importing Images use the standard name of the Image. `Example: ELHall1.png`.

To workaround `<Image>` tag I use the help of `Dimension` API in React-Native to auto set the width and height of the Image most of the time.

Example: `var {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');`

For Example, if the Image has to cover the whole screen, I would do,

```
 <View style={{flex:1,width:"100%",height:"100%"}}>
    <Image style={{width:width, height:height}} source={require('./assets/ELHall1.png')}  /> 
    // width & height is auto taken using Dimension API
    // To play around pixels use resizeMode= ("contain","center") (Keep this as last option)
  </View>
```

I Hope I could help you.

Comment: I don't want to cover just the whole screen, I want to display the image in its natural size and the problem is the quality. In RN 0.56 it displays with no issues but in RN 0.57 it loses its quality.

Comment: Then in that case use resizeMode:"center" and nothing else. It will constrain the Image to its actual size.

Comment: I'll give it a try and I'll reply back here

Comment: I have made a small mistake in the previous comment, its resizeMode='center'. It should be used as a image prop.

Comment: Unfortunately none of the `resizeMode` options is working, neither `center`. I laso tried and created copies with `@xX` names `ELHall1@1x` , `ELHall1@2x`, `ELHall1@3x` but the quality is still the same.

Comment: Would suggest you to give a sample resource file so I could test it from my end. Have you tried other Images ? Are you getting the same results ?

Comment: I will create a github repo containing the image file tomorrow when I'll get to the office. I don't want to try another file, the exact same file works just fine in RN 0.56.

Comment: I have uploaded a github repo. Check the question to get the link.

Comment: Do check out issues section in your Github repo. I have updated my result.

Answer (score 0):

It is the way to apply @clytras' patch to an existing project.
And it cannot run android simulator anymore. I am always testing on real devices.

1. Add scripts to package.json

```
"fresco-clone": "git clone https://github.com/facebook/fresco.git android/libraries/fresco && cd android/libraries/fresco && git checkout tags/v2.1.0",
"fresco-patch": "yarn file-patch ./patches/DecodeProducer.java.diff android/libraries/fresco/imagepipeline/src/main/java/com/facebook/imagepipeline/producers/DecodeProducer.java",
"fresco-setup": "yarn fresco-clone && yarn fresco-patch"
```

2. Create patches/DecodeProducer.java.diff

'yarn fresco-patch'

Result

```
@@ -7279,32 +7279,35 @@

+// 
 if (mDownsampleE
@@ -7381,24 +7381,27 @@

+// 
   ImageReque
@@ -7460,24 +7460,27 @@

+// 
   if (mDowns
@@ -7513,24 +7513,27 @@

+ //
        %7C%7C !U
@@ -7587,36 +7587,39 @@

+//

+ 
 encodedImage.set
@@ -7637,32 +7637,35 @@
 %0A               
+ //
          Downsam
@@ -7700,32 +7700,35 @@
 %0A               
+ //
              req
@@ -7762,32 +7762,35 @@

+// 
             requ
@@ -7820,32 +7820,35 @@
 %0A               
+ //
              enc
@@ -7866,32 +7866,35 @@

+// 
             maxB
@@ -7914,32 +7914,35 @@

+// 
   %7D%0A            
@@ -7937,32 +7937,35 @@

+// 
 %7D%0A%0A             
@@ -7962,24 +7962,27 @@

+ //
  if (produce
@@ -8002,28 +8002,31 @@

+//

+ 
 .getImagePip
@@ -8050,24 +8050,27 @@

+ //
      .getExp
@@ -8091,24 +8091,27 @@

+ //
      .should
@@ -8151,24 +8151,27 @@

+// 
   maybeIncre
@@ -8206,32 +8206,35 @@
 %0A               
+ //
  %7D%0A%0A
```

3. Edit android/settings.gradle

Add `includeBuild ('libraries/fresco')` before `include ':app'`

```
rootProject.name = 'YOURPROJECT'
...
includeBuild ('libraries/fresco') 

include ':app'
```

4. android/build.gradle

Use gradle dependency is 3.4.1

```
dependencies {
  ...
  classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1")
  ...
}
```

5. Run script

`yarn fresco-setup`

6. Download android ndk

I used r21 version.

https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads

7. Unzip and move the ndk

Unzip NDK 
I unzipped ndk to `Users/YOURNAME/Library/Android/android-ndk-r21`
And create `android/libraries/fresco/local.properties` in your project

```
ndk.dir=/Users/YOURNAME/Library/Android/android-ndk-r21
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

8. Run android

That's all.

`yarn android` and check the large image quality.

Thanks to @clytras

> https://github.com/clytras/react-native-fresco

Original my answer: https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/2397#issuecomment-626631033

Answer (score -1):

```
type StyledImageProps = {
  draftsMode: boolean;
  height: number;
  width: number;
};

export const StyledImage = styled(FastImage)<StyledImageProps>`
  height: ${({ height }) => `${height}px`};
  margin: ${({ draftsMode }) => (draftsMode ? '8px' : '0')};
  width: ${({ width }) => `${width}px`};
`;        



<ImageZoom
      cropWidth={width}
      cropHeight={height}
      imageWidth={width}
      imageHeight={height}
      >
      <StyledImage
        draftsMode={draftsMode}
        height={height}
        resizeMode="contain"
        source={{ uri: poster }}
        width={width}
        key={asset.id}
        style={{ height: height, width: width }}
      />
    </ImageZoom>
```

Thats the way its working for me and its not effecting the quality of the image at all, regardless of how much i zoom the image

Answer (score -4):

Use 'ImageBackground' instead for large images.

```
import {
  ImageBackground,
} from 'react-native';


<ImageBackground source={require('./assets/ELHall1.png')} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}></ImageBackground>
```

Comment: still in low quality