# React Native disable Fresco image downsampling

Tags: android, react-native, fresco

I need to disable *Fresco* downsampling for the `<Image/>` component and I read that *Fresco* needs to be initialized inside `android/app/src/main/java/com/<project>/MainApplication.java`.

[Fresco > Resizing/Downsampling](https://frescolib.org/docs/resizing.html)
[Fresco > Configuring the Image Pipeline](https://frescolib.org/docs/configure-image-pipeline.html)
[RN issue report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53402308/react-native-0-57-x-image-large-images-low-quality)

I found two ways to do it but none of the themes worked and couldn't have *Fresco* image downsampling disabled:

1st override `onCreate` and initialize *Fresco* like this:

```java
@Override
public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();

  Context context = getApplicationContext();
  ImagePipelineConfig config = ImagePipelineConfig.newBuilder(context)
    .setDownsampleEnabled(false)
    .build();
  Fresco.initialize(context, config);

  SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
}
```

2nd initialize Fresco using `MainReactPackage` inside `getPackages`:

```java
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  Context context = getApplicationContext();
  ImagePipelineConfig frescoConfig = ImagePipelineConfig.newBuilder(context)
    .setDownsampleEnabled(false)
    .build();

  MainPackageConfig appConfig = new MainPackageConfig
    .Builder()
    .setFrescoConfig(frescoConfig)
    .build();

  return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
    new MainReactPackage(appConfig),
    new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage(),
    new FastImageViewPackage()
  ));
}
```

I'm currently on *RN 0.60.5* and I'm extending `MainApplication` with `com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationApplication` because I'm using [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation).

My question is how can I disable *Fresco* image downsampling.

Comment: Facing same in react-native 0.61

Comment: @AnuragChutani the solution for now is to clone the Fresco repo, comment the downsampling code and then compile Fresco and create your custom binaries which will be included in the APK. See this thread and my comment here https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/2397#issuecomment-541802753

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWGae.jpg) is my report to the support team.

Comment: I sent the report of my violation. don't worry. all downvotes will revert, and also I asked them to punish me. I'm light now. thanks for your responses.

Comment: Yeah, You right, Ok, here is 5 a.m. I'm awake to pray, I sleep now and after awaking I will make a list of my ugly deeds. then I make a little change to them and revert what I did. thanks.